# Implementation logic of datatable rowkey attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm creating a js based datatable component in JSF. I want to know the logic behind the  primefaces datatable's rowkey attribute to identify the selected row / filtered values efficiently.

Comment: I hope you know the PrimeFaces source is open. You can download it and debug it step by step to see what the rowkey does and how it is used. And if you ask such a basic question, may I suggest to refrain from developing a component yourself but fully base it on an existing one (e.g. adapting the PF one regarding css)

Comment: Any feedback???

Comment: Thanks kukeltje.. i checked in primefaces source and implemented the same in my component.